# Can the same device be connected to different IoTF organizations?

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot

I've been able to register and connect a device to my IoTF organization using similar steps as [this recipe.](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/how-to-register-devices-in-ibm-iot-foundation/).

Now, if I try to follow the same steps to register the same device to a different (colleague's) IoTF organization, it does not connect. For this second organization, I created the same Device Type, but I used a different device ID and token.

I'm wondering if the MAC address of the device is used behind the scenes by IoTF/Bluemix. If so, then it might be preventing the connection to the second org. I've gone as far as deleting the device from the first org, but still no luck.

Any advice is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: How are you storing the device information?  Do you have an cfg file that is being used? The MAC address should not affect your ability to connect.  The Watson IoT Platform will check your credentials that are presented when your device connects.

Comment: Yes I am using a device.cfg file that contains the organization id, device type, device id, and token info.  Credentials - Is it checking that the device id and token are correct for the organization or something more?

Comment: If your device.cfg is updated with the new information for the org, device type and deviceID and token,  then it should be able to connect.  How are you connecting?   What error are you getting?

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought too.  The device attempts to connect over secure-mqtt.  I looked at a packet capture yesterday and there was some handshaking going on.  TCP negotiation between device and us.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com occurred but the connection was ultimately rejected.  Unfortunately, I don't have any more details than that right now.  (I'm not stuck on this right now, but would like to know for future reference.  I could provide more information next week perhaps.  If I provide the org ids, can you look on server side?)   Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Mea cupla..Did some further debugging on this and determined that I jumped to an incorrect conclusion.  The clientID used in the non-working case was too long.  The clientID is made up of the organization, device type and device ID.  The first two are the same but for the non-working case I used a device ID which was too long.  The call to MQTTSerialize_connect was failing because the combined buffer was longer than 100 bytes.  Valerie is correct that the MAC address does not affect the ability to connect.  Apologies and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The MAC address does not affect the ability to connect.  The clientID is made up of the organization, device type and device ID.  If you use a device ID that is too long it may be truncated if the combination is too long for the buffer.